# The proof for proving irrationality of square roots.

Tags: real-numbers, irrational-numbers

I was doing a problem where I had to prove that $\sqrt5$ was irrational, and I went through with the usual method. Then, I was curious what would've happened if I tried to do this with a value whose square root **was** rational, such as $\sqrt4$.

Let's assume that we do not know that $\sqrt4$ is rational or not.

Let's assume $\sqrt4$ is rational.

$\sqrt4 = p/q$
$4 = p^2/q^2$
$4q^2 = p^2$

This means that 4 is a factor of p.

Let's assume p = 4x

This means that:

$4q^2 = 16x^2$
$q^2 = 4x^2$

This means q is also a factor of 4. But, here we are making the assumption that p and q are co-prime, so this contradiction occurs when we assume that $\sqrt4$ is rational, and hence $\sqrt4$ is irrational.

The contradiction method seems to suggest that $\sqrt4$ is irrational, even though we know that it equals 2 which is rational. Did I make a mistake somewhere? Or is the perhaps a problem in the contradiction method?

Comment: To find your mistake, since you know $\sqrt{4}=2$, you could go through each step with $p=2$ and $q=1$ to find the first claim which is not true. (The first answer has already pointed out the same spot.)

Comment: For the future: I assume you *know* that $2$ is a (rational) square root of $4$. So why did you not take that solution (say $p=2, q=1$), and go through your "proof" line by line to see where your proof is off? Then you would have seen the first three lines are fine for you $p,q$, but the line "This means $4$ is a factor of $p$" would be the first wrong one for your $p=2$. And indeed that is the wrong line in the proof, as the answer shows.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I understand what you mean. Thanks a lot for clearing this misconception for me.

Comment: Ha, was typing why @aschepler was expressing the same idea.

Comment: @aschepler Thanks a lot to you too sir/ma'am!

Answer (score 3):

$4q^2=p^2$ means $4$ is a factor of $p^2$. That does not mean $4$ is a factor of $p$, since $4$ is not prime (it might be, it might not be). Assuming $p,q$ are coprime, you can only guarantee $2$ is a factor of $p$. If $p=2x$, then $4q^2=4x^2\implies x=q$ ($p,q$ can obviously be taken positive) so that $p/q=2$.

You conclude that, if $p/q$ is a coprime rational representation of $\sqrt{4}$, then $p/q=2$. That's ok, because $\sqrt{4}$ is indeed equal to $2$.

Comment: Wait, I am confused, let's say we are gonna try the same with the square root of 15. In the process, not even 15 is prime, but then how does this explanation work for proving square root of 15 is irrational?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it now. thanks a lot!